# How do you get reference to object after adding it to a HashSet in rust?

Tags: rust

I have a struct with a `HashSet` inside it. I am imagining the HashSet should own the strings, but when I insert (and thus move ownership) into the `items` HashSet, I loose access to the string. What is the normal solution for this?

```
pub struct UniqueUuid {
    items: HashSet<String>,
}

impl UniqueUuid {
    // Generate, remember, and return a uuid.
    pub fn next(&mut self) -> &String  {
        loop {
            let id = random_string(10);
            if self.items.contains(&id) {
                continue;
            }
            self.items.insert(id);
            return &id; // ERROR
                   ^^^ returns a reference to data owned by the current function
        }
    }
}
```

Full code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cf89f81ea1988f1f8b69fe17ef423d23

I understand that there is an "experimental" [`get_or_insert_owned` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.get_or_insert_owned) added 5 years ago that never made it into Rust proper, which might solve this. But I don't know if I want to use something that is experimental but never accepted.

Comment: Note that this will essentially "freeze" the `HashSet`, disallowing modifications while the reference is alive.

Answer (score 4):

Like you found on nightly you can use `get_or_insert_owned` or since you already have a `String` `get_or_insert` might be more appropriate.
If you don't want to switch to a nightly compiler or wait for those methods to stabilize both methods are available on [`hashbrown::hash_set::HashSet`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/latest/hashbrown/hash_set/struct.HashSet.html)
Since you already know the element isn't in the `HashSet` you could also use [`insert_unique_unchecked`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/latest/hashbrown/hash_set/struct.HashSet.html#method.insert_unique_unchecked) which also returns a reference.

```rust
use hashbrown::has_set::HashSet;
pub struct UniqueUuid {
    items: HashSet<String>,
}

impl UniqueUuid {
    // Generate, remember, and return a uuid.
    pub fn next(&mut self) -> &String  {
        loop {
            let id = random_string(10);
            if self.items.contains(&id) {
                continue;
            }
            return self.items.insert_unique_unchecked(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful. It didn't occur to me to investigate alternate non built in options. It appears that it would avoid creating a copy. 

That said, it still seems strange to me that this is not possible in the standard library. It made me think I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Rust is a relatively new language and the standard library is far from complete, it's common for features to exist in the crates eco system long before they get included in `std`. Returning a reference also isn't all that useful in Rust since you can only ever have one such reference because all the methods keep the `HashSet` mutably borrowed as long as you have that reference.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, **it is very likely that you want to use `Rc<str>` or `Arc<str>`** instead of `String`.

```
use std::{any::Any, collections::HashSet, rc::Rc};

pub struct UniqueUuid {
    items: HashSet<Rc<str>>,
}

impl UniqueUuid {
    // Generate, remember, and return a uuid.
    pub fn next(&mut self) -> Rc<str> {
        loop {
            let id = random_string(10).into();
            if self.items.contains(&id) {
                continue;
            }
            self.items.insert(Rc::clone(&id));
            return id;
        }
    }
}

fn random_string(_: impl Any) -> impl Into<Rc<str>> {
    "Any string is fine.".to_owned()
}
```

Acquiring a reference to `HashSet` element will always immutably borrow (freeze) the whole set however you implement it. Any mutation on `HashSet` invalidates references to elements in C++, but Rust won't allow ref. invalidation at all.

**Reference counters will give you freedom of shared access.**

Answer (score 2):

In stable Rust you can insert a clone, then look up and return a reference to the inserted string. This avoids the lifetime error you were getting when returning a reference to a local variable.

```
pub fn next(&mut self) -> &str  {
    loop {
        let id = random_string(10);
        if !self.items.insert(id.clone()) {
            continue;
        }
        return self.items.get(&id).unwrap();
    }
}
```

It is unlikely that the insertion will fail in practice, so you can also get rid of the `contains` check. It's simpler and more efficient to just try the insertion and `continue` if it fails. That way there's only one lookup done instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to make two copies of each string. One copy to hold in the HashSet and one copy to return.

Although the easiest solution does not seem the best solution, because that means this function literally creates two String objects when only one is needed.

```
 pub fn next(&mut self) -> String  {
    loop {
        let id = random_string(10);
        if self.items.contains(&id) {
            continue;
        }
        let copied = id.clone();
        self.items.insert(id);
        return copied;
    }
}
```